# Displaying yAxsis data for columnrange highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a column range highchart . it works fine but it doesn't display time on yAxsis but tooltip does. it is in json  format (tooltip time ) .

Any help appreciate ..

my yAxsis looks like this

```
yAxis: {

  type: 'timepicker',
  labels: {
    formatter: function () { //1262334143000
      return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M %p', this.value);
    }
  },

  title: {
     text: 'Y Sside New'
  }
},
```

there is `this.value`  it has json date.

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtkd9096/3/)

Comment: Just change this strange `timepicker` to `datetime`, see [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.type).

Comment: i forgot to update the code here .bujt when it is datetmie it shows all 00:00 am and when it is timepicker it dislpays unmeaningfull hours on YAxsis . I mean very far from tooltip result  , check js fiddle

Comment: Sorry, but in tooltip, all I can see is just numbers. In that case just change formatter to get the same result: http://jsfiddle.net/gtkd9096/2/

Comment: Please check it now, I updated it . http://jsfiddle.net/gtkd9096/3/

Comment: Set a smaller [tickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickInterval) on yAxis.

Comment: I tried but no luck .My question is , the tooltip starting and ending time is far away from Yaxsis value when it is match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It displays the time in `%H:%M:%P` (in your JSFiddle), which is hours, minutes and am/pm.

Why does it all say 00:00:am? Because Highcharts has figured that the most reasonable spacing between ticks is some exact number of days, all starting at midnight. To see that they are not all the same you can add day, month, year or similar to the formatter. You can also manually control the tick spacing, if that is desired. See [`tickInterval` in the API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickInterval) and similar yAxis options.

Your formatter isn't selecting when ticks occur, only what text they show. To check this you can do:

```
yAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b %H:%M:%P', this.value);
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Y Sside New'
    }
}
```

Which adds the day of the month and month name, and you can see that they are different.

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/gtkd9096/1/).