# Highchart doesn't dispaly a datarange even if there is data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have line highcahrt and it displays well except one of the data range. On the same page there is a chart and grid just under the chart. and task names sorted on yAxsis and each task name has starttime and endtime . And these results displays in the grid. one of the task name let's call `mytask` has start and endtime in json format like others. and it dispalys it in chart js file and in grid

```js
yAxis: {
    tickInterval: 1,
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            if (tasks[this.value]) {
                return tasks[this.value].name;
            }
        }
    },
}
```

I debugged it and I can see its name here and in `series` I can see it is start and end time . But I can't see datarange on chart . I checked everything but no luck

Any help appreciate

[I would post images but my reputation is very low ]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying yAxsis data for columnrange highchart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25390410/displaying-yaxsis-data-for-columnrange-highchart)

Comment: It is a different question .This one belongs to different chart with different issue

Comment: Instead of images, provide jsFiddle example with issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue . I is about min and max  in XAxsis .

```
xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {

                        var mycharttime = Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%P', this.value);

                        return timsesubstringforXaxis(mycharttime);
                    }
                },
                min: start_chart_scale_dt,
                max: end_chart_scale_dt,

                title: {
                    text: displayMonthXaxiesTitle,
                    align: 'low'
                }
            },
```